# call js function from php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a js file.

**jiten.js**

```
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    return p1 * p2;   
    };
```

I have to call this function from php file

**Demo.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Mosquitto Websockets</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jiten.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <?php 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">myFunction(2,4);</script>'; 
?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

But When I run this file, I get nothing....

Comment: What do you expect it to do?  What you have above will call the function, which will do as expected, but then simply return a result.  It doesn't _do_ anything with the result.  Put it in an alert and you should see that it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP and JavaScript are different languages, they can be embedded but, each language has to call its own functions.

You are returning value through JavaScript code, but, you can not echo it with PHP and not printing it through JavaScript.

You need to print the value by using `document.write()` in JavaScript.

Corrected Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
  return p1 * p2;   
  };
</script>
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(myFunction(2,4));</script>';
?>
```

Output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working well, but your Javascript function **doesn't display anything**, it just returns a value.

You should use something like `console.log()` or `alert()` to [display](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp) the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(myFunction(2,4));
```